# Ambiguous MVC Route Resolver UI

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to create a UI for times when there is an ambiguous routing. For example suppose I have a domain called ping.com and I want to have the urls

http://ping.com/10.3.2.4

and

http://ping.com/hostname.com

I'd like to show an AJAX UI that shows that I'm seeing if it's an IP address, then if it's a hostname, etc.  I'd also like to refresh resolution progress, get a report of what worked what didn't.

> The purpose is  to educate the
>   end user who is hacking my urls, to do
>   it right, and to slow down invalid
>   attempts.

Of course in this over simplified example I could transparently redirect to the right controller, but in a more complex resolution example, this may be helpful.

How would you approach this problem? What technologies would be involved?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably punch everything through to a controller who's job it is to sort this stuff out and serve the correct view.

If I had to do it using routing, you could get pretty close with some route constraints limiting the "ping url" controller to pinging things that looked like IP addresses, etc. I guess one could get as far as going into custom route constraints and such, but if you are going that far, you might as well just make a controller . . .